# ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 for Custom Employee User account

Tags: apex, custom-controller, userrecordaccess

When i create new User Account and login with that credentials, it gives me this problem if admin doesnt have set thier values yet !!!**

```
AllotmentList = [select id, Days_Remaining__c from PTO_Allotment__c where Year__c =:year and Employee__c=:EmployeeList[0].id LIMIT 100]; //access only Current user Allotment details
                //to handle Listoutof Bound Exception wrote if-else

        if(AllotmentList.size()>0)
        {
        requests.PTO_Allotment__c=AllotmentList[0].id;
        requests.Days_Remaining__c=AllotmentList[0].Days_Remaining__c;
        }
        else
        {
            //write a code when AllotmentList is empty ....

       }
```

Comment: I have tried isEmpty() also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you're querying with the employee id, you have to verify if it exists. For instance:

```
if(employeeList.isEmpty()){
        // continue your business logic in an alternative track
        AllotmentList = [SELECT id, Days_Remaining__c 
                         FROM PTO_Allotment__c 
                         WHERE Year__c =:year 
                         AND Employee__c=:EmployeeList[0].id LIMIT 100
                        ];

        // do some error messaging here maybe
}else{
        // process as expected
       AllotmentList = [SELECT id, Days_Remaining__c 
                        FROM PTO_Allotment__c 
                        WHERE Year__c =:year  LIMIT 100
                       ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, I am done with it, I was missing that only, Now I checked for the Emp record too first and it worked.